# LDAP "force-change-on-add" can't be handled properly

Tags: ldap, opendj

I'm using openDJ LDAP server for authentication process of a Java based project using JNDI.
Most of the other things like password expired, invalid credentials can be handled using exceptions. (using the understandable message in exception, or using the error codes in some occasions)

`ds-cfg-force-change-on-add` and `ds-cfg-force-change-on-reset` attributes are set to true in the password policy.

But when a newly created user logs in or, when a user logs in after a password reset by admin no exceptions occur.

Can somebody tell me how to handle this.

Comment: Consider using the UnboundID LDAP SDK instead of JNDI and the job of troubleshooting code will be much easier. JNDI should not be used for new code. See also: [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks Terry. I will look at it too. However found an alternative way for this force reset problem using the 'ds-pwp-last-login-time' attribute of a user.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative in this case is the password policy request and response controls ([example](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-ldap-sdk-examples/xref/org/forgerock/opendj/examples/Controls.html#431)) defined in draft-behera-ldap-password-policy, supported by [OpenDJ LDAP SDK](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-ldap-sdk/) and other SDKs. You pass the request control to the directory server, and you get back a response control.

The response control indicates whether the password needs to be changed, why a requested password modification could not complete, how much time remains before expiration, etc.